# Activerecord data validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have three Models

`Bid`, `Printer`, `Order`

A printer can have many bids but only one an order.

Im having trouble validating that exact case,  `a printer can have many bids, but only one bid per order`

Are there any validations that have this built in to ActiveModel or ActiveRecord?  If not any ideas on how to ensure a printer can only have one bid per order?

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :printer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids
end

class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, through: :bids
  has_many :bids
end
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `Bid` and `Order`?

Comment: Good question.  Maybe something like this? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated

Answer (score 0):

There might be a slicker way to do this, but you can always just pass a block to `validate`.  Maybe something like this?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :printer
end

class Printer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, through: :bids
  has_many :bids

  validate do
    order_ids = orders.pluck(:bid_id)
    dups = order_ids.detect{ |id| order_ids.count(id) > 1 }
    errors.add(:bids, 'Only one order per bid per printer') if dups.any?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> a printer can have many bids, but only one bid per order

In other words, the values of pairs (order_id, printer_id) must be unique in **bids** table, right? So you only need validate the uniqueness of (order_id, printer_id) in `Bid` model like

```
validates :order_id, uniqueness: { scope: :printer_id }
```

Ok, to clarify my answer, I have an example of **bids** table here.

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| bid_id | order_id | printer_id |
+--------+----------+------------+
|      1 |        1 |          1 |
|      2 |        1 |          2 |
|      3 |        2 |          2 |
|      4 |        2 |          3 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

It's all good: a printer has one bid per order. But what will happen if we add a record like **[5, 2, 3]** into the table? The printer with `printer_id = 3` will have 2 bids (with `bid_id = 4,5`)! The condition is exactly the same with values of pairs (order_id, printer_id) are not unique here!

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| bid_id | order_id | printer_id |
+--------+----------+------------+
|      4 |        2 |          3 |
|      5 |        2 |          3 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```